# Green board with waterproof membrane

Tags: bathtub, ceramic-tile, support

I live in north Atlanta, GA.
The boards behind the tile at my bathtub are wet and need replacement.
The old construction used a green board on top of the drywall (both are wet and in bad condition).

I'm going to remove both and use only one level of boards.

Is it OK to use a green board with Redgard (as a water proofing membrane) instead of cement backer board?

What kind of **Adhesive/cement** should I use. At Lowes, they gave me MAPEI Type 1 to use but the Floor and Decor department told me not to use it as it will allow the tile drop after a while because of the water.

I'm not looking for a life time solution.

My reasons for using green board:

1. Easier to use,to cut and handle for me.
2. I already have the mesh drywall tape and the dry wall screws.
3. cheaper.
4. the James Hardi backer is 0.42" which will not level with drywall in the sides (0.5")

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasons for using green board are valid.   They are along the same lines of reasons for not going to the gym and staying in shape.

1. Driving to the gym takes time.
2. I have more fun on the couch.
3. I sweat and have to do more laundry.

These are lies we tell ourselves so that we feel better doing the wrong thing.

I understand that you don't want to take care of the issue correctly.  I get it.   You don't care about your shower, most don't.   But it isn't about doing this perfectly, it is about how much time you are going to spend doing something wrong multiple times.

Put the green board up, coat it with redgard, stick on your tiles.   The water will just wick to the other areas not covered in redgard or get behind the green board and leak somewhere else.   You will be doing versions of the same thing over and over, you will have mold issues, tiles will fall off.

First there really is no difference between greenboard and drywall.   They are basically the same material and both should not be used in wet areas.   Your question infers that you are using green board (mold resistant) drywall as some sort logical precautionary material.   When in fact it is just a marketing ploy.

The biggest issues that your tub surround has are - it has no moisture barrier and the tiles were not the right fit to go over drywall (you have to basically have to do a perfect job for this to last, grout has to be thin, and grout/tiles waterproof).

You are going to saving yourself a TON of time just ripping these out and starting over.   I have a good answer on here that shows different tub wall installations.   The one I would suggest for you is 1/4" drywall, plastic sheet, 1/4" hardieboard.  It really is that easy and the thinner hardieboard is super easy to work with.   You can do your demo and have your new wall up in about 3 hours.  The tiles depends on the install method and type of tiles.

Comment: Lol,Frankly I watched famouse youtube channel- home renivision DIY,he said this will last 20 years,I liked your idea,but may I know 1. Why using 1/4" drywall and 1/4" cement board (why not 1/2" from the ceiling to the shower area and then 1/2" cement board to the tub . 2. I didn't understand the plastic sheet thing,how to apply it. 3.if I used your way, would it be ok to put the drywall and then redgard, then the cement board and redgard again (instead of the plastic sheet) 4. Shall i use 1/4" regular drywall or green drywall..hope to get answers for my questions and thank you for your help

Comment: The plastic sheething is just stapled on the drywall and is super easy to install - live 5 minutes,   You can buy thick gauge plastic at any big box.   Redgard is fine too - you will redgard the HB - drywall cannot be redgarded (read manufacturer instructions) and you do not want a redgard sandwich.   The reason I suggest plastic to "newbies" is that it is pretty fool proof.   You don't redgard right and water can get through (think corners and seams).   But redgarding the outside is great and acceptable if done right - makes install time longer.

Comment: Also you can just use 1/2 HB but it is harder to install and harder to get flush - very stiff and can pull from studs.   I have a really good answer on here with options - there is a ton of ways to install a tub surround.  I just gave you perhaps the easiest.

Comment: The plastic sheet is very smart,you made it so easy for me,I have one more question,what cement to use over the seems and behind the tile (is the ready adhesive in the picture attached good) or to use the grey cement, the one you mix with water,please advise me a specific name to buy from Home depot or lowes,and just to know if I understood the steps correctly,I will remove the tile and work on the area behind it: 1. Screw into the stud a 1/4" green mold board 2. Staple a plastic sheet all over the area from the side of the tub to the other side 3.

Comment: 3. Screw the James Hardie HardieBacker 1/4 in. Cement Backerboard(from homedepot) into the stud with backer on cement screws 4. Apply two coats of redgard on top of the HB 5. Apply cement on top of the redgarded HB and apply the tile 6.apply 100 waterproof silicon

Comment: I didnt understand this "grout has to be thin, and grout/tiles waterproof" is there a water proof grout? And it should be non sanded right? Can i use the non sanded  grout caulk, the one comes in tube?

Comment: I only found USG Sheetrock Brand 1/4 in. x 4 ft. x 8 ft. Gypsum Panels (regular drywall) is this what you mentioned earlier..thanks

Comment: Yes on the USG panels - that is it.   You should be using thinset for your tiles - adhering them to the HB.   But this also depends on the type of tile you are choosing.   Make sure your plastic sheething is stapled on the drywall and that it extends into the tub.   You will not cut this until after you tile.

Comment: So far this what I finished (new photo added) ,I removed the second layer drywall, shall I now cut the white area (red lined) and then add the 1/4" drywall? Fiber mesh tape and cement above the seems and then the plastic and HB..is this correct?

Comment: If that drywall matches the existing bathroom, take it down, put in the 1/4" drywall, then the plastic sheething over that.   The plastic sheething should stay in one piece - wrap it around tub so that it ends at tub edge on each side, start at top of new drywall, and let it fall into the tub a few inches - you won't cut this until after you tile.   Then add your 1/4" HB and mesh tape.  I don't use the thinset when I am tiling to secure the mesh tape - easy...   Tip for tiling - extend your tile out a little and you don't have to worry about transitions.

Comment: Thank you so much DMoore,you explained everything very well,I took down all the dry walls highlighted in red,While I was waiting for your reply I was thinking and checking Denshield tile backer boards,I asked the manufacturer and they told me that they last for a long time and no need to use any liquid water maembrane with it(as they have it built in),just screw them with corrosion resistant screws only.and for more security I can use your idea and staple the plastic sheets behind them on the studs.I found the size 8'X4' (1/2") which I will end with only 2 seems at the top(photo attached).

Comment: What do you think about this way,I will end with water resistant board and only one layer instead of two (drywall+cement) and only two seems to cover by thin set at the very top of the board which far from water hit (the seem will be at 1" x 5" from the top ( the middle area is 5" X 5" and the sides Is 5" X 3")

Answer (score 1):

Do it right so you do not have to do it again.

I  use [Denshield](https://www.buildgp.com/product/densshield-tile-backer/) for tiling bathroom surrounds. It is the **same thickness as the drywall** this means that there is no transition disparity between the drywall and the DenShield. ( *assuming you have a single layer of 1/2" drywall in the rest of your bathroom* )  It comes with a waterproof membrane already installed on it.

You  use a fiber mesh tape and a liquid waterproof membrane, *like red guard*,  over the seams, corner seams and  also cover any of the screw heads with the waterproof membrane, the rest of the field is already waterproof and textured to except tile.

It is easier to use than cement board, you score it and snap just like drywall.

Place your transition from denshield to drywall so  the final row of tile  is over the  transition joint ( *meshed with membrane* )  of the Denshield to drywall. This insures the last row of tile will cover the transition.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alaska man, travis have  have a single layer of 1/2" drywall in the rest of my bathroom. I never heard of this product, I knew shluter-Kerdi boards but very expensive,I'm assuming densheild is something similar, I didnt find a place to sell near me, can you tell me please how much is the densheild board cost? Thanks for your help